# Deserialize Json with top Array and first unnamed object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am consuming an API that returns the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "product": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Auto"
        }
    }
]
```

So, I am trying to deserialize this in C# object wihout success.

I'd tried a lot of other's stackoverflow solutions.

Here are my attempt:

```
public class DomainMessageResponse : BaseResponseMessage
{
    public Example data { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("product")]
    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the JSON is beginning with [] and our generic method (that I use from an internal framework) was not able to due with it. I'm getting the following exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type....

Thanks @EZI and @eocron for valid solution's.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know http://json2csharp.com? Do you use Json.Net?

Comment: Oh, really? Can you share with us those solutions, so we will know more about problem.

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid JSON ... well not sure whether you meant a JSON array or what?

Comment: @Rahul http://jsonlint.com says it is valid json

Comment: @SirRufo, yes syntactically but with that he may end up with the different model altogether ... may be

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, I know json2csharp and used it, I will update my question with my attempt.

Comment: @Rahul I did not get your point. Many APIs return arrays, so it is very common to me

Comment: @eocron I've tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345152/how-to-deserialize-a-json-array-with-no-name

Comment: @eocron tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816903/deserializing-an-unnamed-array

Comment: Hi, I am getting this exception from Newtonsoft: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type..... I will verify what are wrong. But I don't understand why too many downvotes, I am asking for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should deserialize to array/list. Below code should work...

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);

public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my guess .. OP probably meant a `Product[]` instead

Comment: Nice. But, In my company we are working with SOA and we have some Frameworks, one of them is to do Get from external API's and I discovered that our method is not prepared to work with this type of JSON (with array in beginning).

So, I appreciate a lot your answer. It is valid and works very well. I'd test it with some piece of the Json.

Answer (score 1):

There is two solutions to your problem, considering the way you want to use your object.

First one is to simply create **DTO** with same fields. Used when you need full control:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Example
        {
            [DataMember]
            public Product Product { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Product
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"
                            [
                                {
                                    ""product"": {
                                        ""id"": 2,
                                        ""name"": ""Auto""
                                    }
                                }
                            ]";

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(json,
                                                         new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                         {
                                                             ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                                                         });
        }
    }
}
```

The second one used when you want a few fields from json and don't care much about everything else, and uses **dynamic** type. Easy to code, easy to use, looks pretty good, but not very safe:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"
                            [
                                {
                                    ""product"": {
                                        ""id"": 2,
                                        ""name"": ""Auto""
                                    }
                                }
                            ]";

            dynamic list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);
            var id = (int)list[0].product.id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eocron. Your solution works very well.

I've asked for our Architect to implement a solution to due with JSON that begins with [ ].